# Catch and log errors before ASP.NET Core host starts in an AppService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, azure-web-app-service, serilog

Our ASP.NET Core app hosted in an Azure App Service is using Serilog for logging.

We've noticed that if there are errors during the host startup, then they will not be logged. This is easily fixable by moving the Serilog configuration to happen before the Host build+start instead of inside it:

Problem:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); })
        .UseSerilog((context, loggerConfig) => { loggerConfig.WriteTo.SomeLogger(); })
        .Build()
        .Run();
}
```

Not a problem:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    try {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.SomeLogger();
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); })
            .UseSerilog()
            .Build()
            .Run();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
    } finally {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}
```

However, if you need to do some extra orchestration (like get some data from a key vault that serilog needs) then we've got a problem:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    try {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.SomeLogger(loggerSecret: KeyVault.GetSecret("foo"));
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); })
            .UseSerilog()
            .Build()
            .Run();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
    } finally {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}
```

If the Key Vault retrieval fails, the the logger initialization will also fail, so even if the exceptions is caught, then the `Log` will still be uninitialized and the failure will not be logged.

The `Log.Logger` line could probably be in a `try/catch` of its own, but if I just do a `Console.WriteLine()` in the catch, this will not be easily retrievable in an AppService.

How can we make sure that exceptions that occur before the logger is initialized is properly handled and can be discovered somewhere in an AppService?

Comment: If vault value required for logging, then you cannot log vault error because you don't have value required for logging

Comment: Unfortunately you'll need to bootstrap and configure Serilog before anything else. In my projects I do this by providing Serilog configuration in an environment-variable or command-line argument (this is configurable in Azure App Services).

Comment: @Dai Bootstrapping and configuring Serilog before anything else is what I'm trying to do. What I'm asking is that if an exception occurs during this bootstrapping, then we will have no way of figuring out what went wrong.

Comment: @GTHvidsten you can write message to stderr, eventlog or whatever you have available for your service. so that you can go and check manually why it's not starting